# MS Excel conditional formatting by date formula does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I need to apply conditional formatting on cells containing dates (expiration dates of certificates). I want expired certificates in red, expiring withing a week orange, expiring within a month (30 days) in yellow and others unmarked (talking about background colour). But when I put formula
`=A2-today()<0` all cells get filled red, regardless the date. When I change the number to 7 and select orange colour, they all cells get filled orange, again regardless of the date. If everything worked fine, the A2 cell should be orange right now. What do I do wrong? How shall I write the formula?

Comment: Your formula works for me. Are you sure your dates are actually dates and not text that looks like a date?

Comment: Yes, when I check the filter in the cell A1, I see dates in the list. I mean the expanding tree, where you can browse the dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions:

[DATEDIF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjg1u-ar_nxAhWJILcAHXECBY4QFjARegQIGBAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Foffice%2Fdatedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DCalculates%2520the%2520number%2520of%2520days%2Cincorrect%2520results%2520under%2520certain%2520scenarios.&usg=AOvVaw1GFSA06akltxVxJZkLWLAu)

[TODAY](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiIu9uzr_nxAhXiH7cAHRTTAx8QFjAJegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Foffice%2Ftoday-function-5eb3078d-a82c-4736-8930-2f51a028fdd9&usg=AOvVaw1qGJdb6MNnwmKViFUU8CoX)

---

This gives the number of days between today and the date in A2:

`=DATEDIF(A2, TODAY(), "d")`

So, you can use:

`=DATEDIF($A2, TODAY(), "D") > 0` **[select red color for this formatting]**

`=AND(DATEDIF(TODAY(), $A2, "D") >= 0, DATEDIF(TODAY(), $A2, "D") < 7)` **[select orange color for this formatting]**

`=AND(DATEDIF(TODAY(), $A2, "D") >= 7, DATEDIF(TODAY(), $A2, "D") < 30)` **[select yellow color for this formatting]**

You can go to this link and search for the section called "**Highlighting delays**":
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/04/using-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-dates-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Check that your rules are in the right order.  They're applied in the order shown.

Also check that you're not using an absolute reference (e.g., no dollar signs).  Try highlighting the range before you type in your formula.  If you format the first cell and fill down, it's more problematic.

Here, they're out of order, so they all end up yellow.

[image]

Here, the order is corrected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I test on my environment, please try following is helpful.

Red --- Expired certificates, the formula could be `=AND(A2-TODAY()<0,A2<>"")`

Orange --- Expiring withing a week, the formula could be `=AND(A2-TODAY()>=0,A2-TODAY()<7)`

Yellow --- Expiring within a month (30 days), the formula could be `=AND(A2-TODAY()>=7,A2-TODAY()<30)`

[image]